# Inner Join of two IObservables

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

What's the best way to join two IObservables into one the same way as IEnumerables can be joined using LINQ Join method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: A`Join` is very different from a Cartesian Product.  Which do you actually want?

Answer (score 1):

You really need to make the question clearer. An `IObservable` can emit items spaced out over time. If you're joining Observable-A and Observable-B, and one emits item 1 an hour after the other, does that satisfy the condition?

The following code demonstrates an inner join on two observables assuming you don't care at all about what time the items are emitted, which one was emitted first, or the relative time between them:

```
var factorsOfTwo = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Select(i => i * 3)
    .Take(10);

var factorsOfThree = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Select(i => i * 2)
    .Take(10);

var factorsOfBothTwoAndThree = factorsOfTwo.Join(factorsOfThree,
        i => Observable.Never<object>(),
        i => Observable.Never<object>(),
        (a, b) => Tuple.Create(a, b)
    )
    .Where(t => t.Item1 == t.Item2)
    .Select(t => t.Item1);

factorsOfBothTwoAndThree.Subscribe(l => Console.WriteLine(l));
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't (regardless if you want a join or a cartesian product). The `IObservable<T>` interface serves the purpose of subscribing to notifications, nothing more, nothing less.

However, if your are sure the `IObservable<T>`s are `IEnumerable<T>`s, too, then just cast them to `IEnumerable<T>`. Needless to say, this may not be the best possible design.

Comment: That's like saying that `IEnumerable` just lets you get the next element of a sequence, nothing more, nothing less.  Technically it's true, but there are all sorts of operations that you can perform given anything capable of doing that thing, such as transforming each one of those items into another one, or joining those items with items from another sequence.  The same logic applies to `IObservable`.

Comment: So what would be the best approach to find same elements in two IObservable streams and push them to another IObservable?

Comment: @MT Apparently, you should edit your question and provide more details on what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Even if the purpose of Enumerable and Observable are indeed quiet different, on some occasions, like enormous amount of data, Observable is the only solution to outclass what Enumerable can't always do.
This is why SSIS (an etl) is based on the paradigm of reactive programming, even if it doesn't look like it because its designer is a visual tool. Like in SSIS, the reactive programming version of join can be done and needs both streams to be sorted not to consume too much memory. The rest of the implementation is based on a simple smart merge of these 2 streams.